# Connect-SPOService ... Error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powershell, administration, multifactor-authentication

I want to connect to SharePoint online SharePoint admin center using this code:

```
Connect-SPOService -url $TenantAdminUrl -Credential $SPCredential
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Stacktrace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.Common.ConfigureSharePointContext.ConfigureClientContext(String url, String userId, String password)
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.Program.AddGroups(Dictionary`2 listval, List`1 groupData)
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Stacktrace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.Common.ConfigureSharePointContext.ConfigureClientContext(String url, String userId, String password)
   at Microsoft.Legal.MatterCenter.CreateGroups.Program.DeleteGroups(Dictionary`2 listval, List`1 groupData)
17/06/2022 17:29:00 - Creating group and adding users to it failed
```

Now I know that `Connect-SPOService -url $TenantAdminUrl -Credential $SPCredential` does not work while MFA is enabled. so that why we disable the MFA for all users, and when users try to access any SharePoint site using the web-browser, they will not be asked for MFA, then will just get this message:

[image]

so could this message be the issue? and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Online Management Shell to connect with multi-factor authentication (MFA) enabled SharePoint site using below command:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com
```

Follow below documentation:

[To connect with multi-factor authentication (MFA)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?#to-connect-with-multifactor-authentication-mfa).

---

For more information & other ways to login when MFA is enabled, check this thread: [Connect-SPOService : The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/302388/connect-sposervice-the-sign-in-name-or-password-does-not-match-one-in-the-micr)