# Connect-SPOService : The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, pnp-powershell, pnp

I am running this power shell command:

```
$username = 'admin***@M*****.onmicrosoft.com'
$password = '******@@'
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOService -Url https://****-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred
```

but I will get this error:

```
Connect-SPOService : The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-SPOService -Url https://*****-admin.sharepoint. ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-SPOService], IdcrlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.Connec
   tSPOService
```

Although I am passing accurate username/password, and using the same credentials I can access the SharePoint admin site from the browser. where after entering the username/password I will get this message on the browser:

[image]

and clicking on next I can access the SharePoint admin site.

Any advice?

Comment: Is MFA enabled for this user account?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes it is

Comment: try below suggestions in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Online Management Shell to connect with multi-factor authentication (MFA) SharePoint Site.

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com
```

Follow below documentation:

[To connect with multi-factor authentication (MFA)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?#to-connect-with-multifactor-authentication-mfa).

---

**OR**

**Using PnP PowerShell `UseWebLogin`**:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl –UseWebLogin
```

OR

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive
```

[image]

---

**OR**

**Using App Password**:

Also, you can use **App password** in place of normal password to login easily.

I am using App Password for authentication in PowerShell as well as SharePoint Designer and it works well.

[Create an app password for Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-app-password-for-office-365-3e7c860f-bda4-4441-a618-b53953ee1183).

---

**Similar thread**: [The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275517/the-sign-in-name-or-password-does-not-match-one-in-the-microsoft-account-system/275520#275520)

Comment: The important thing is to *leave out the credentials* so that the web login is shown.